# Publishing App in Android Market

Tags: android

I have published an app in the Android Market yesterday. It has been more than 15 hours since I have activated and published the app.

But still I am not able to see my app in the market. I tried with the format:

http://market.android.com/details?id=com.android.example

and I also searched for the app name.

Is it that it takes time to become available in the market, or is there another issue?

Comment: Wait...... it will take maximum 7 days to approve your application and will available in market.

Answer (score 0):

No the android application is instantly available in the market. Retry and check the status of your application in your developer console.

Make sure you have published it worldwide and not in selected countries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please tell me how to check in developer console

Comment: https://market.android.com/publish/Home

Comment: It is showing Published there. But still not able to see the app

Comment: thats weird, does it show any rating or install?

Comment: what is the name of your application? package name?

Comment: com.intware.android.quickcall     :    App Name : Quick Caller

Comment: Its coming fine now.. Sent a mail to support group and they did the job